Preserving Build Progress When Switching CMake Generators (Ninja -> Unix Makefiles)
I've been working on a project using Ninja as the cmake generator, but I've encountered memory issues during the build process. I'm considering switching to Unix Makefiles. However, I want to avoid rebuilding everything from scratch to save time and resources specially that I only have like 400 files left from more than 2000 originally.
Is there a way to leverage the Unix Makefiles generator while retaining the partial build progress made with Ninja?

I don't understand the question.  The entire purpose of using make is to avoid rebuilding everything from scratch.  Else you would just write a shell script that compiled all your files.  Are you under the impression that avoiding recompilation of up-to-date files is somehow a feature unique to ninja?

Moreover, make relies on file timestamps to evaluate whether built artifacts are up to date with respect to their corresponding sources.  Its analysis will not be confused by the absence of a build database such as a few build systems use (dunno about Ninja in particular).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@MadScientist Hi. No I understand that all build systems (or most of them, I can't say for sure) have this feature, but my question is: Can I stop the current build process which is running using ninja, and restart another build process of the same project using make, but without losing the progress achieved with ninja? What I did was deleting the CMakeCache and this recompiled the whole project.

You should be able to do this because make doesn't have its own "database" of what's up to date.  It uses only the metadata that the filesystem maintains on every file automatically (the time last modified info).  So, it is not a requirement that you update files with make, you can update them with any tool, including just running a compile command yourself directly at the command line.  When make runs it will see that the modification time of the target is newer than its prerequisites, and it won't build the target.

@MadScientist Oh I see. Thank you for  your clarification. But for some reason, when I stopped the current build (ninja), deleted CMakeCache and ran make, it started recompiling the whole project.

Wait; "deleted CMakeCache"? CMakeCache is a part of the cmake project, which is not either Ninja or GNU Make.  cmake uses those tools, but nothing in your question or previous comments suggested you were using cmake.  Are you are really asking if you re-run cmake with a different generator (switch from the ninja generator to the makefile generator) will it re-use the results from the previous generator?  If so, your question is completely unclear and misleading.  Please edit it to say what you really want to do.  You should also add a cmake tag and remove the ninja and makefile tags.

@MadScientist I think you may help me reformulate my question. Here is what happened:
-I run cmake -G Ninja ......
-The build process was eating all of the available memory no matter how much i give it until i got to 14gb
-I read that "Unix Makefiles" may use less memory than Ninja in the building process
-I decided to change the generator, so I rerun cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ........
-at this point I get an error saying : Generator Does not match the generator used previously: Ninja

Either remove the CMakeCache.txt file and CMakeFiles directory or choose a different binary directory.

Yes, you have to remove cmakecache.txt in order to rebuild your cmake project with a different cmake generator.  But that's not related to whether you can re-use already-built object files.  See my answer.

So I deleted the CMakeCache, changed the generator, and ran make -C ./build
following these steps, the project started re-compiling from scratch and i lost the progress that i had when using ninja as generator.

Okay I see, I will change my question now, thanks. What's the answer though ?

Reload your page to see the answer I posted.

The answer to your question, if you are really using cmake, is "no, results will not be reused".  But that's not really related to ninja or make, per se, it's to do with cmake and the fact that cmake generates ninja files that handle the builds differently from the makefiles that it generates.
The makefiles that cmake generates contain rules that create .d files, containing the prerequisites (headers) for each object file.  The makefile rules in the generated makefiles will consider the object files out of date if that file is missing.
The ninja files that cmake generates do not create the .d files.
So, if you build half your project with cmake-generated Ninja files then you switch to cmake-generated makefiles, the .d files are missing and make will rebuild everything so that the .d files are generated.
I know of no way to work around this.
